# How to get addresses from a transaction's vin?

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, multi-signature

How can i decode addresses from the following transaction's vin.

Transaction:

https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/ed8286d06f6df2269e8481b37bbc532c11d80bd2d1b155c920a0742daf3185b2

There are

Example for an address
https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/address/m-3c0cd9cd5bdd9d778d9fe4fe4af1a67e

Comment: You can't. That information is not part of transactions. You'd need to look up the transaction whose outputs are being spent, and compute their address. In general there should not be any need to do so, except for debug purposes.